# Trying to write a basic main program using a function

Tags: c, assembly, mips, mips32, pcspim

I am trying to write a function to copy words from source memory to destination memory.

I have written the function but I am having difficulty executing the code.
It is giving me `execption 4` as an error

```
.data    
.text      
main:

.setnoreorder      
top: beq $a2,0,done 
lw $t1,($a0) 
sw $t1,($a1) 
add $a0,$a0,4 
add $a1,$a1,4 
j top     
sub $a2,$a2,1


done:   
jr  $ra     #return to the main program 
add $0, $0, $0  #nop
```

I want to write a main program which calls this function to copy 800 words from
address 0x50000 to 0x90000 in memory. But when I add the values in $a0-$a2 and run the code it doesnt work.
Does anyone know how to fix it. (I am converting C code to MIPS which is why I have included a C tag

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    .text                       # code starts here 
main:                           # required label
    la      $a0,dest            # point to destination
    la      $a1,srce            # point to source
    li      $a2,1000            # move this many words 
    jal     block_copy          # call the routine 
    nop
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

###############################################################################
#   block copy - moves $a3 words from $a1 to $a0
#
#   register usage:
#       $a0 address of destination 
#       $a1 address of source
#       $a2 block size (number of words to move)
#       $v0 return code (0 means no troubles)
#
block_copy:

    move        $v0,$a2         # counter/rc 
bc_loop:
    lw          $t0,0($a1)      # no DMA here
    sw          $t0,0($a0)      # we have to move a word at a time 
    addiu       $a0,$a0,4       # point to next word in destination
    addiu       $a1,$a1,4       # point to next word in source
    addiu       $v0,$v0,-1      # decrement counter 
    bgtz        $v0,bc_loop     # keep on moving if counter is positive 
    jr          $ra             # return to caller
###############################################################################

    .data 
dest:
    .word       9:1000          # destination 1000 words (all zeroes)
srce:
    .word       0:1000          # source 1000 words (all nines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be:

```
sub $a2,$a2,1
j top
```

Comment: As I recall, the MIPS has a branch delay slot. It does not execute the branch until after the instruction that follows the branch. Typically, the default for an assembler is to take instructions in the order they should be executed and reorder them to account for that. But this code has `.setnoreorder` at the top, which presumably tells the assembler not to do that, to assemble the instructions in literal order.

Comment: @EricPostpiscil: True, but the question is tagged "pcspim", a MIPS simulator which has the option to not delay branches.

Answer (score 0):

You show a delay slot in two places, here

```
j top     
sub $a2,$a2,1
```

and here

```
done:   
jr  $ra     #return to the main program 
add $0, $0, $0  #nop
```

But apparently not here:

```
top: beq $a2,0,done 
lw $t1,($a0)
```

Maybe the problem is that the load following the beq is, in fact, a delay slot and is being executed even when $a2 is zero (and the branch is taken) - you are loading from memory at ($a0) even when the count is zero - perhaps accessing invalid memory and causing the exception.